# How can I transition to a new view controller within the same window? (Swift/Storyboard, macOS)

Tags: swift, storyboard, viewcontroller

I am creating a project that requires changing views. However, no matter what segue I choose, the new view opens in a new window when I press the button to open the new view. Is there any way to have the new view replace the old one in the same window, either programmatically or within the Storyboard?

Comment: Have one parent view controller and add replaceable ones as child view controllers to it.

Comment: Do you really mean _Window_? I doubt you mean it, rather a new view controller. There are ways to have parent and child view controllers, where the child view controller's view is embedded within the parent's VC view. And you can also switch in and out child view controllers and their views.

Comment: Have you set a name on your segue? If so, you can call ```self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SEGUE_NAME", sender: self)``` or you can call [presentViewController:animated:completion:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-presentviewcontroller). I personally ditch storyboards entirely and create the navigation stack programmatically, which requires you to embed your view controllers in a [UINavigationViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the term you want to search for is **view controller containment**.

Here's the basic idea: Apple ships its own "container" view controllers like `UINavigationController` and `UITabController`, which manage view controllers for you (i.e. how they are presented, how you transition from one to the next). If those don't work for you, you can build your own (which can themselves be used within those built-in containers btw). Here's some documentation:

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-use-view-controller-containment

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html